# Group daily data in to months and count objects per user

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to group a product count by month and user. I have daily data so first I have group it in months and then per user. See the table below:

```
Date         UserID Product
2016-02-02  1   Chocolate
2016-03-03  22  Chocolate
2016-03-03  22  Banana
2016-03-03  22  Banana
2016-03-03  22  Chocolate
2016-04-03  22  Chocolate
2016-04-03  22  Banana
2016-04-03  33  Banana
2016-04-03  33  Chocolate
2016-04-03  22  Peanuts
2016-04-03  33  Peanuts
2016-04-03  33  Peanuts
```

My result should be something like:

```
Date     UserID   Product     Count
2016-03  22       Banana      2
2016-03  22       Chocolate   2
2016-04  22       Banana      1
2016-04  22       Peanuts     1
2016-04  33       Banana      1
2016-04  33       Peanuts     2
2016-4   33       Chocolate   1
```

I need to do this with python pandas and am not able to

with this code

```
dfcount = df(['Date','UserID','Product']).Kit.count()
```

I do get a count but per day, how can I do it per month?

I tried this:

```
df[['Date', 'UserID', 'Product']].groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1M')).sum().sort_values(by='Date', ascending=True)['Product']
```

It did not work

It returns that it dows not recognize my product column, but probably my grouping is wrong.

---

> KeyError: 'Product'

Comment: Try: `df.groupby(['Date', 'UserID', 'Product']).count(),reset_index()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first convert the column to Datetime, because that makes it easy to extract the year/month/day (by doing `df.<date column>.dt.<year/month/day>`).

```
df['Date'] = df.Date.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Then, to group by month, customer, and product:

```
counts = (df.groupby([df.Date.dt.month, 
                      'UserID', 
                      'Product']).count())
print(counts)

                       Date
Date UserID Product        
2    1      Chocolate     1
3    22     Banana        2
            Chocolate     2
4    22     Banana        1
            Chocolate     1
            Peanuts       1
     33     Banana        1
            Chocolate     1
            Peanuts       2
```

Here, if you get more data that spans more than one year, the above solution allows you to still group by month alone. If instead, you want to group products and users by year as well as month in this new expanded dataset, you can simply add the year extraction to your groupby like so:

```
counts = (df.groupby([df.Date.dt.year, 
                      df.Date.dt.month, 
                      'UserID', 
                      'Product']).count())

print(counts)

                            Date
Date Date UserID Product        
2016 2    1      Chocolate     1
     3    22     Banana        2
                 Chocolate     2
     4    22     Banana        1
                 Chocolate     1
                 Peanuts       1
          33     Banana        1
                 Chocolate     1
                 Peanuts       2
2017 2    1      Chocolate     1
     3    22     Banana        2
                 Chocolate     1
```

This way, you're being more explicit about how you are grouping your data (and are therefore a bit less likely to wind up with unexpected results later on)

Answer (score 0):

If `Date` is a string, you can

```
df.groupby([df.Date.str[:7], 'UserID', 'Product']).count()

                          Date
Date    UserID Product        
2016-02 1      Chocolate     1
2016-03 22     Banana        2
               Chocolate     2
2016-04 22     Banana        1
               Chocolate     1
               Peanuts       1
        33     Banana        1
               Chocolate     1
               Peanuts       2
```

With a datetime column:

```
df.groupby([df.Date.dt.to_period('M'), 'UserID', 'Product']).count()
```

Comment: Both of these solutions works for the example given, but it should be noted that this actually groups by year and month, not just the month. So if you have multiple years of data and want to group just by month, you should either do `df.Date.str[5:7]` for a string, or do `df.groupby([df.Date.dt.month, 'UserID', 'Product']).count()` for a datetime column

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.to_period('1M')
df['Count'] = 1
df.groupby(by=['Date','UserID','Product']).agg({'Count':'sum'}).reset_index().sort_values(by=['Date','UserID'])
```

**Output:**

```
+---+---------+--------+-----------+-------+
|   |  Date   | UserID |  Product  | Count |
+---+---------+--------+-----------+-------+
| 0 | 2016-02 |      1 | Chocolate |     1 |
| 1 | 2016-03 |     22 | Banana    |     2 |
| 2 | 2016-03 |     22 | Chocolate |     2 |
| 3 | 2016-04 |     22 | Banana    |     1 |
| 4 | 2016-04 |     22 | Chocolate |     1 |
| 5 | 2016-04 |     22 | Peanuts   |     1 |
| 6 | 2016-04 |     33 | Banana    |     1 |
| 7 | 2016-04 |     33 | Chocolate |     1 |
| 8 | 2016-04 |     33 | Peanuts   |     2 |
+---+---------+--------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: added to each line to compute the 'Count' column later in the `df.groupby(...).agg({'Count':'sum'})`.
`df.groupby(...).size().` could have led to the same result but you would have to rename the last column to "Count"